# $\int_{[a,b]} z \mu(dz)=\int_a^b \mu([x,b])dx$

Tags: measure-theory, self-learning

Let $\mu$ be a measure on $[0,1]$.
Show that 
$$\int_{[0,1]} z \mu(dz)=\int_0^1 \mu([x,1])dx.$$
It looks simple, but I am unable to prove it.

Comment: The tag description of ```self-learner``` specifically says: "Don't use this tag just because you were self-studying when you came across the mathematical question you're asking; it is only for when the fact that you're self-studying is what your question is about." Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

$\int_0^{1} \mu [x,1]dx=\int_0^{1}\int_{[x,1]} 1d\mu (z) dx=\int \int_0^{z}dx d\mu(x)=\int zd\mu(z)$. The second equality follows by Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: I understand that $\mu([x,1])=\int_{[x,1]}\mu(dz)$. Now I realize what you did with the integral limits in the second equlity. But how to apply Fubini's Theorem when one integral is w.r.t. $\mu(z)$ and the other w.r.t. $x$?

Comment: The fact that $\mu$ and $m$ may be different measures is irrelevant- Draw the picture of a square, $m$ going along the $x$ axis, $\mu$ along the $y$ axis. Draw the diagonal from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1).$ You are integrating over the upper triangle. Now apply Fubini.

Comment: @Matematleta The Fubini's theorem I learned assumes two measure spaces. In this case, one space has measure $\mu$, and what is the measure behind the other space?

Comment: The second measure is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.